# Attempt to index local 'file' (a nil value) at file:write

Tags: lua

i'm very new to lua scripting, i'm starting with create and write text to file by Lua with this script:

```
A = "Hello"
local file = io.open ('test.txt',"w")
file:write(A)
file:close()
```

And I got this error:

> :3 Attempt to index local 'file' (a nil value)

What's wrong here?

P/s: I'm running this lua on camera with CHDK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

io.open will return nil if it was unable to open the file. You can retrieve the error message:

```
A = "Hello"
local file, err = io.open ('test.txt',"w")
if file==nil then
    print("Couldn't open file: "..err)
else
    file:write(A)
    file:close()
end
```

See: http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html

Comment: Thanks, i run your script and it's say "Couldn't open file: test.txt",  so what i have to do now to create and write text to a file?

Comment: Are you certain you should be able to create that file in the directory your script is running in? Because that code should be working otherwise.

Comment: Agree, it's probably a permission issue. I think you'll need to check the CHDK documentation. If you follow the link I posted, it shows how to retrieve the error number as well, which is system dependent. Hopefully you would be able to look it up in CHDK docs.

Comment: @Etan Reisner Right, that's permission problems, unlock the sdcard resolve it.